# (public, subscribable, widgetable) calendar system (ics?)

Tags: html, wordpress, calendar, icalendar

So, to make it clear, this is what I want:

-Make a calender that I can easily edit, preferably on my phone
-Make this calendar public
-Display this calendar in the sidebar of a wordpressblog
-Enable people to subscribe to this calendar, preferably on phone.

The most logical thing for this in my mind would be an iCalendar .ics file, but I'm struggling for a lightweight way of displaying the info on a website. The embeddable info would preferably be a list of the next 10 events.

Anyone has a suggestion to a solution to this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Google Calendar: https://www.google.com/calendar/‎ ? That should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I missed a chunk of settings when I looked at it. embarassing. But ok, thank you!!